# Facebook PHP SDK: (#200) Subject does not have permission to post videos on this target

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook-PHP SDK to upload videos to a page
using user access token  and Facebook app that has the `mange_pages` and publish_pages permissions.

And it worked fine until yesterday.
suddenly it stopped with this error message:

```
(#200) Subject does not have permission to post videos on this target
```

I checked the user Apps from the Facebook profile and the app exists with the right access

```
Manage your Pages
Show a list of the Pages you manage
Show a list of the Pages you manage
Publish as Pages you manage
```

tried to refresh the long-live access token
but I still have the same issue

what I should do/debug/check ??

Comment: What kind of token you are actually using in the API call to post the video. It sounds like your page access token expired/was invalidated, and now your app tries to post with just a user token instead, to a page that does not allow users to upload videos.

Comment: you can try obtaining a new token instead of refreshing token

Comment: Was this ever solved?

Answer (score 1):

You should try to set 2 factor auth for your FaceBook account.